Асинхронный вывод в консоль выводит текст на той же строке где она принимается
Для своего приложения сделал команды в консоли для отладки, а также есть логирование в консоль и в файл. Понятное дело что ввод у меня в другом потоке (Класс наследуется от QThread и использует QTextStream с readLine для ввода с консоли), потому иногда логи пишутся сразу после строки которую я ввожу. Например, у меня есть команда help, и пока я ее пишу у меня появляется лог, который пишется сразу после еще не введенной команды 
Как мне сделать так, чтобы ввод перемещался ниже при новом логе?

Логировать в файл, этот файл показывать tail -f  в отдельном окне терминала.

Использовать ncruses или другую TUI библиотеку.
